# White vertical line between 2 divs

Tags: html, css

How can I get rid of this little white line between the two divs? I have cleared padding, margins, borders and checked to make sure its not the body showing through a gap but I still can't figure it out.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
}

#side {
  width: 2.5%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  background-color: #000;
}

#top {
  width: 97.5%;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 2.5%;
  
  background-color: #969696;
}
```

```html
<div id="side"></div>
<div id="top"></div>
```

Comment: Where is the little white line??? I can't see nothing??? what browser you are using? Your code looks perfectly ok to me. No line should be / is there.

Comment: Just to the left of #top. I took a screenshot to post but even in the screenshot its not visible. Here is a picture of it I took with my phone (excuse the bad quality) https://imgur.com/a/kXIg7Kw

Comment: if you change `left:2.5%` with `right:0`?

Comment: Is it happening when you are zooming?

Comment: If there really is a gap under some circumstances, a workaround could be to have if start at left:0, put it below the black bar with z-index and give it a left padding of 2.5%.

Comment: In some widths on some browsers (not most), I can see a red bar to the right of the grey bar caused by rounding errors.

Comment: I've been messing about with it for a while now and the line is still there but now its black and very hard to see on my main monitor so it's fine but I have no clue how I changed it and it's still clearly visible on my second monitor which leaves me stumped. I guess I'll just see how it goes